# ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid when creating VIEW object

Tags: database, oracle

Im triying to create a new view but ORA-00980 appears in the first line, here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tr_v_tipos_documentos...
```

More views are created succesfully before in the script but this one is annoying me. I tried to create with force option, searched for synonyms or different objects with the same name and put the schema name before object name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that oracle could not locate the object a synonym used in view creation is referencing. Could be due to:

1. The object the synonym refers to was dropped, or the user owner of the table was dropped
2. The object the synonym refers to does not exist (not that the object need not currently exist and you need not have privileges to access the object at the time of synonym creation!)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The problem is not an object referenced within the view, but the view itself that I am creating.

Comment: I meant the view could not be created because it is referring a synonym that is no longer valid. Can you try the select statement of the view on its own? use `where 1=2` if you think that select is going to do an expensive query.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was inside the select statement because there is a column that doesnt exist in the table that im referencing.